Carbon interprets P1M in ISO 8601 as 1 minute instead of 1 month
I am using Laravel 11 and trying to work with ISO 8601 intervals using Carbon. However, I encountered an issue where Carbon interprets P1M as 1 minute (60 seconds) instead of 1 month. This is causing problems with my time calculations.
$interval = CarbonInterval::fromString('P1M');
echo $interval->totalSeconds; // Outputs: 60 (expected: seconds for 1 month)

As a temporary workaround, I’m using P30D to represent approximately one month.
Is there a way to make Carbon correctly interpret P1M as 1 month? Or is there a better approach to handle this in Laravel 11?
Any advice or guidance would be appreciated!

It's actually PHP's DateInterval that has that problem, Carbon just inherits it. Can you use some of CarbonInterval's other methods, such as CarbonInterval::month() or CarbonInterval::createFromDateString('1 month')?

@aynber PHP's DateInterval works as expected:   https://3v4l.org/18qgs

And CarbonInterval too if you use it the same way (using new) the format expected by fromString is given here in the doc: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ > click on Reference and search "fromString"

@Olivier Ah, I missed the section about adding T for the time designation.

fromString is from "human" string.
If you want ISO string use the normal construct:
$interval = new CarbonInterval('P1M');
echo $interval->totalSeconds;

Format for fromString from the doc:
CarbonInterval::fromString
string $intervalDefinition
returns CarbonInterval
Creates a CarbonInterval from string.
Format:



Suffix
Unit
Example
DateInterval expression




y
years
1y
P1Y


mo
months
3mo
P3M


w
weeks
2w
P2W


d
days
28d
P28D


h
hours
4h
PT4H


m
minutes
12m
PT12M


s
seconds
59s
PT59S



e. g. 1w 3d 4h 32m 23s is converted to 10 days 4 hours 32 minutes and 23 seconds.

I find differece
php artisan tinker                                                                                                        ─╯
Psy Shell v0.12.4 (PHP 8.3.6 — cli) by Justin Hileman
> Carbon\CarbonInterval::fromString('P1M')->totalSeconds;
= 60.0

> Carbon\CarbonInterval::fromString('PT1M')->totalSeconds;
= 60.0

> (new Carbon\CarbonInterval('P1M'))->totalSeconds;
= 2419200.0

> (new Carbon\CarbonInterval('PT1M'))->totalSeconds;
= 60.0


Again fromString('P1M') makes no sense, fromString is not parsing the given string as an ISO 8601 interval.
